# Current class on admin menu using add_submenu_page()

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, design

I am working on creating an administration menu within WordPress for a plugin. I have successfully registered the menu using add_menu_page() and it shows in the sidebar as expected. I have also added a couple of sections within the menu using add_submenu_page().

It appears that WordPress (running 3.05) is not correctly indicating which menu item should be activated as "current".

When I add a test page to the main Dashboard menu this is what I see:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3019972/wp-screen1.png

As you can see the current page is visually correct within the menu and is given a class of "current". However on my own menu it looks like this:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3019972/wp-screen2.png

In this example I would expect "Dashboard" to be highlighted.

Is this simply a WordPress bug? or do I need to provide special code to make this work within my own menu?

**Updated with code examples**

The code I am using for adding and creating menus looks like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu','my_admin_menu');

function my_admin_menu() {

// this test works as expected
// add_submenu_page( 'index.php', 'test', 'test', 'read', 'admin.php?page=plugin-dashboard','my_pluggin_dashboard' );

// my main menu menu    
add_menu_page(__('My Plugin', 'myplugin'),__('My Plugin', 'myplugin'), 'edit_posts','admin.php?page=plugin-dashboard','my_plugin_dashboard','icon');

// dashboard submenu - this fails to highlight with current
add_submenu_page('admin.php?page=plugin-dashboard', __('Dashboard','myplugin'), __('Dashboard','myplugin'), 'edit_posts', 'admin.php?page=plugin-dashboard', 'my_plugin_dashboard' );

// settings submenu - this fails to highlight with current
add_submenu_page('admin.php?page=plugin-dashboard', __('Settings','myplugin'), __('Settings','myplugin'), 'manage_options', 'admin.php?page=my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_settings' );

}
```

I have commented the code that works and the code that does not behave as I expect. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Is your dashboard the current page? (or is that a duplicate link to the WP dashboard) If you're duplicating the WordPress dashboard link, there's no way the menu will know to apply a current class, it's just not that smart. It would help if you posted the code you're using to to add the menu items.

Comment: Please post your code. If you simply add a submenu to your self-created main menu, highlighting should work out of the box. If you do more tricky stuff, see Mike's post or my response in Question [7029].

Comment: @t31os I am adding my own dashboard menu and not moving the WordPress dashboard. I have added my code. @wyrfel I was expecting it to work out the box as well. I wonder if perhaps something is conflicting with my menu.

Comment: Get rid of the `admin.php?page=` part.. (basically what wyrfel posted, mark his answer correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_menu_page(__('My Plugin', 'myplugin'),__('My Plugin', 'myplugin'), 'edit_posts','my-plugin-dashboard','my_plugin_dashboard','icon');

// dashboard submenu - this fails to highlight with current
add_submenu_page('my-plugin-dashboard', __('Dashboard','myplugin'), __('Dashboard','myplugin'), 'edit_posts', 'my-plugin-dashboard', 'my_plugin_dashboard' );

// settings submenu - this fails to highlight with current
add_submenu_page('my-plugin-dashboard', __('Settings','myplugin'), __('Settings','myplugin'), 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_settings' );
```

Essentially: don't use full page links with admin.php?... as the page slug. Especially if you are passing callbacks, just use a slug, not a page address.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP, but in my case the submenu links to `edit-tags.php`, so I can't use a proper slug. Any suggestions?