# submenu item edit a specific post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, sub-menu

I'd like to have a submenu item in the admin section link directly to the edit form for a specific post ID, a custom post type at that.

Basically looking at using the add_submenu_page function to add the menu item http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page which is easy.

Any ideas how to write a callback function to display the edit form for a specific post ID (which, in this case, happens to be a custom post type)?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a callback function at all.
You could display (yet another) custom edit screen, but if the custom post type is set up correctly you should be able to reach it simply by pointing to `http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=9999&action=edit` where `9999` is any post ID that corresponds to a post of said type.

Hence you can use `post.php?post=9999&action=edit` as the menu slug (see the codex page of [add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page#Parameters) for reference on parameters) with [`add_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page,) and you're good to go:

```
add_submenu_page(
    'parent_slug',
    'Edit My Special Post', // page title, change to liking
    'Edit SP', // menu title, change to liking
    'edit_posts', // required capability, change to liking
    'post.php?post=9999&action=edit' // menu slug, change post ID
);
```

The last parameter, the callback function, you don't need at all.

Comment: That worked, except when I select that submenu option, while I'm taken to the correct edit form, the parent menu is closed and the menu item is not highlighted.

Comment: @Uysrc & Johannes, this can be solved using jQuery and wrapping the `page title` above with a `<span id="my-title" />`, check [this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75411/12615).