# Wrong current class on admin menu with add_submenu_page()

Tags: admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I'm writing a plugin that displays a post/page list in the admin menu, as a submenu for each post type. Here's the code I've got far: http://pastebin.com/DmUGfzxN

The lists are showing and linking fine. However, I have a problem when I go to another menu, for example, Media, and go to edit a post (or image in this case). The *current* class that WordPress uses for the admin menu points to the wrong place, and opens the menu for Pages, highlighting the last submenu item.

I believe this is a related problem here: [Current class on admin menu using add_submenu_page()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9832/current-class-on-admin-menu-using-add-submenu-page)

He solved it by adding the submenu page to a page slug, instead of a link like `admin.php?=page...`.  Unfortunately, I want my submenus to be under Post, Page, etc., so I need to use `edit.php` and `edit.php?post_type=...`.

If anyone has any ideas how to get around this quirk/bug, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I got it solved. I listed the pages *without* using '<ul>' and '<li>', and just highlighted the current page with my own class. This avoids the default admin menu opening up on the wrong page.

Comment: Please add solution you came up with as an answer so that others can benefit from it and question doesn't haunt site as unanswered. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the code:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Menu Post List
Plugin URI:
Description: Display a simple post list in admin menu for easy access
Version: 0.2
Author: Eliot Akira
Author URI:
License: GPL2
*/


/*
 * Load CSS in header
 */

function custom_post_list_view_css() { ?>

        <style>
                .post_list_view_headline {
                        padding-left: 10px !important;
                        padding-right: 10px !important;
                }
                .post_list_view_post {
                        margin-left:12px;
                }
                .post_current a {
                        color:white !important;
                }
    </style>

<?php }
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_post_list_view_css' );


/*
 * Admin Menu Post List
 */


add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_post_list_view');
function custom_post_list_view() {

        /*** Get options ***/

        $post_types = array( 'post', 'page' );

        $current_post_ID = $_GET['post']; /* Get current post ID on admin screen */

        foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

                $custom_menu_slug = $post_type;
                $output = '';

                $args = array(
                        "post_type" => $post_type,
                        "parent" => "0",
                        "post_parent" => "0",
                        "numberposts" => "-1",
                        "orderby" => "menu_order",
                        "order" => "ASC",
                        "post_status" => "any",
                        "suppress_filters" => 0
                );

                $posts = get_posts($args);

                if($posts) {

                        $output .= '</a>';

                        $output .= '<div class="list_view_' . $post_type . '">'
                                                . '<div class="post_list_view_headline">' . '<hr>' . '</div>';
                        foreach ($posts as $post) {
                                $edit_link = get_edit_post_link($post->ID);
                                $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
                                $title = esc_html($title);
                                $output .= '<div class="post_list_view_post';
                                if($current_post_ID == ($post->ID)) {
                                        $output .= ' post_current';
                                }
                                $output .= '">'
                                        . '<a href="'
                                        . $edit_link    . '">'
                                        . $title . '</a></div>';

                                /*** Search for children? ***/

                        }
                        $output .= '</div>';

                        $output .= '<a>';

                        if($post_type == 'post') {
                                add_posts_page( "Title", $output, "edit_posts", $custom_menu_slug, "custom_post_list_view_page");
                        } else {
                                 if ($post_type == 'page') {
                                        add_pages_page( "Title", $output, "edit_pages", $custom_menu_slug, "custom_post_list_view_page");
                                } else {
                                        if($post_type == 'attachment') {
                                                 add_media_page("Title", $output, "edit_posts", $custom_menu_slug, "custom_post_list_view_page");
                                        } else {
                                                add_submenu_page(('edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type), "Title", $output, "edit_posts", ('edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type), "custom_post_list_view_page");
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        } // End foreach post type
}

function custom_post_list_view_page() { /* Empty */ }
```

Now it displays the submenu, and the *current* class doesn't affect it. Where I output the submenu, I changed the `<ul>` and `<li>` to `<div>`. I added a check to see if the menu item equals the current post being edited, and a little CSS in the admin_head to highlight the item. Please refer to the code paste above.

Next, I'll be looking into displaying child pages.